# How can I show that the Mercator projection is in the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Define a function $f: \Bbb R×(0,2 \pi) \to \Bbb R^3$ (Mercator projection) by:

$$f(u,\theta) = {1 \over {\cosh\,\, u} }\begin{pmatrix}\cos\,\, \theta\\\sin\,\, \theta\\\sinh\,\, u\end{pmatrix} $$

How can I show that $f(u,\theta)$ is in the sphere $S$ (given by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What happens when you compute the quantity

$$ \frac{ \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta  + \sinh^2 u}{\cosh^2 u}= \frac{1 + \sinh^2 u}{\cosh^2 u} ?$$

Comment: $\frac{1 + \sinh^2 u}{\cosh^2 u}=1$

Comment: @Fayz So this now means that....?

Comment: could you tell me the steps please, what should I do to get this result?

Comment: @Fayz Every point in the image of $f$ can be described as 

$$\left( \frac{\cos \theta}{\cosh u}, \frac{\sin \theta}{\cosh u},\frac{\sinh u}{\cosh u} \right). $$

Now what does it mean to say that the image of $f$ lands on the sphere?